# Access a form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display the triangle to the first Form (called `MainForm`), I created another form (`CarreGen`) who asks to user to choose a value between 1 and 15 (X and Y), but the thing is I linked the forms together, when I click the button, the triangle doesn't show.

Label to display = lblResultat

PS : I tried to search for the answer, but I'm still stuck at this error.

MainForm.cs :

```
private void carréToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    carrG.Show(); //declared before
}

public void GenCarre()
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < carrG.nombre; i++) 
        {
            lblResultat.Text = "\n";

            for (int j = 0; j < carrG.nombre; j++) 
            {
                lblResultat.Text = "\t \t *";
            }
        }

        Figgen();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erreur lors de la génération.");
    }
}
```

CarreGen.cs :

```
public partial class CarreGen : Form
{
    public int nombre;
    public bool CGen;

    public CarreGen()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    void Figgen()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Figure générée avec succès !", "Succès", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void btnGenCarre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormMain mform = new FormMain();

        if(!int.TryParse(txtInt.Text,out nombre))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Vous n'avez pas saisi un chiffre !", 
                "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if(int.TryParse(txtInt.Text,out nombre))
        {
            if (nombre <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La valeur est inférieure à 1.\nVeuillez saisir une valeur entre 0 et 15.","Erreur",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (nombre > 16)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La valeur est supérieure à 15.\nVeuillez saisir une valeur entre 0 et 15.", "Erreur",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                Hide();
                mform.GenCarre();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erreur lors de la génération du carré.", "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd form is closing before you are returning results.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Interesting, will try and I will tell if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use interface to connect your forms.

Here is my solution:

- Create new Interface `IRequestor` that will have only one method.

  ```
  public interface IRequestor
  {
      void SetNumber(double valueBetween1and15);
  }
  ```
- Modify your `MainForm` to use this interface, e.g.

  ```
  public partial class MainForm : Form, IRequestor
  {

      public MainForm()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }


      private double number;

      public void SetNumber(double valueBetween1and15)
      {
          number = valueBetween1and15;
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          var carreGenForm = new CarreGen(this);
          carreGenForm.ShowDialog();

          // After that you can use 'number'

          // further code
      }
  }
  ```
- Modify `CarreGen` form to have a link to `IRequestor`:

  ```
  public partial class CarreGen : Form
  {
      private IRequestor requestor;

      public CarreGen(IRequestor requestor)
      {
          this.requestor = requestor;

          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void BtnGenCarre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          // some code...
          double number = 17;

          // Send value to MainForm
          requestor.SetNumber(number);

          // Close form
          this.Close();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: This will not work.  The 2nd form gets disposed before the first form reads the return value.

Comment: Nope, the second form (`CarreGen`) sends a number to the first one and only then closes

Comment: Really.  Look at code again!!!  this.close disposed the 2nd form before the 1st form ever gets to read the number.

Comment: Then you have a race condition that you are just lucky that one process executes before the other disposes the object.

Comment: To be honest `this.Close()` is not necessary there.The second form could be closed by a user on cross button or smth else. But it sends data to the first form.

Comment: A form always get disposed unless you capture the close event like in my link.  See my comment in Ops question.